# Android : is it possible to call requestFeature() after setContentView ?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I would like to call requestFeature() after my view is load with setContentView(), but the error is pretty clear :

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

There is no way to call requestFeature() directly in an activity ?

Comment: requestFeature cannot be called but if it is for views then you can use view.requestLayout() to again call layout pass for that view

Comment: `is it possible to call requestFeature() after setContentView?` **NO** As your logcat tells you: `requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: "I would like to call requestFeature() after my view is load with setContentView()" -- why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to change my view using setContentView(), and with the new view activate voice command feature. I will update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the developer's site about **[requestFeature()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29)**:

> Enable extended screen features. This must be called before setContentView(). May be called as many times as desired as long as it is before setContentView(). If not called, no extended features will be available. You can not turn off a feature once it is requested. You canot use other title features with FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE.

So the simple answer is no.

Comment: Ok thanks, pretty bad for some feature like voice command, I would like to activate them depending on the context. Is it possible then to have a first view, then use setContentView() to go to the second view and call requestFeature() between the 2 views ?

Comment: @Pull to have a first view you will need setContentView(). Even if you are adding view programmatically you will need to call setContentView(). You can call setContentView() twice but I am not sure if you can call requestLayout() in between. I guess it needs to be done before first setContentView() is encountered.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I am doing it wrong (new with Android), there should be a way to load a new view with the feature that I need in it.

Comment: @Pull why not add it to the old view then. That way it will be available to other also.

Comment: I found that startActivity() could work. When you say add it, I don't really know how to add an entire layout above another.